# C# WPF KeyDown не отслеживает Key.Space

Tags: c#, wpf

Не могу найти информацию почему пробел в конечном счете пропускаете и обрабатывается, а, к примеру, клавишу A нет

```
<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key is Key.Space or Key.A)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании PreviewKeyDown проблема отсутствует. Аналогичная ситуация с использованием TextInput, пробелы благополучно игнорируются. С чем это связано и должно ли так работать?

Comment: Вы не правильно делаете сравнение... Прочитайте что делает оператор `is`.

Comment: Используйте `PreviewKeyDown`. и вот это еще `if (e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.A)`

Comment: @aepot, нельзя обрабатывать клавиши в PreviewKeyDown, нужно чтобы ТС для нужных кнопок там установил `IsInputKey` в `true` и обрабатывал клавиши дальше в `KeyDown`.

Comment: @Kotomi кто сказал, что нельзя?

Comment: @aepot Так сказано в документации.